# How do I fix a broken path to NPM and perhaps Node

Tags: node.js, bash, macos, ubuntu, npm

I think I've done a Very Bad Thing and removed the path to my npm install somewhere. I vaguely remember running `rm -rf usr/bin/local/npm` (approximately) during an install of something else (my main goal is updating node and npm) and I think I ran into an error with that file so I deleted it. Probably stupid, yes, and I should learn what's happening in my computer before I mess with it. Anywho, I think that deleted npm (or the path to it) so I tried following [these instructions](https://gist.github.com/DanHerbert/9520689) to reinstall node and npm on my system. However, I still think the path is broken.

When I run `node`, I can run node in my terminal.

When I run `node -v` I get `v8.4.0`

When I run `whereis node` I don't get any output.

When I run `which node`, I get `/usr/local/bin/node`

But anytime I try to run `npm <anything>` I get the error: 
`-bash: npm: command not found`

The last line of the resource I used `curl -L https://www.npmjs.com/install.sh | sh` I believe should install npm, but something is still broken.

Any help would be extraordinarily appreciated. I'll never do it again I promise. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you tried `which node` to check the node binary path?

Comment: Thanks shaochuancs -- `which node` returns `/usr/local/bin/node`, I'll add that to the post.

Comment: Can you run `ls -l /usr/local/bin/node` to check whether `node` is a symbolic link?

Comment: Sure, I'm not sure how to tell if this is a symbolic link, but here's what I get: `-rwxrwxr-x  1<name>  wheel    35M Aug 26 16:12 /usr/local/bin/node*`

Comment: It's not a symbolic link... just a plain binary file. Sorry but I'm not able to provide help on this issue :(

Comment: No worries. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the command line processes for installing NPM would not fix this problem, so I just ran over to npmjs.org and downloaded the stable version. That seemed to fix it.